# Is it possible to send erc20 token when I have 0$ ether but $1000 in the token?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, contract-invocation

Long story short I have $1000 in one erc20 token contract but 0$ in ETH.
Can I at least transfer these $1000 from the token to another address without ethereum asking for gas? That is: just change owner of token funds without transaction occuring on the ethereum blockchain? 10x!

Comment: No you can't...

Comment: You could try sending a transaction with a gas price of 0, the caveat being that it might take a while for your transaction to be mined... (We're on a fairly high pending count currently: https://etherscan.io/txsPending)

Answer (score 0):

No. In order to make *any* changes to data on the blockchain (ie, the owner of your tokens), you will need to make a transaction, and therefore pay transaction fees. Transaction fees have to be paid in Ether.